# Bot Framework V3 - How to define HandleSystemMessage

Tags: bots, botframework

I'm struggling to port my bot from V1 to V3 using Microsoft Bot Framework.

If I'm not able to find any full example to download then I'm in trouble with HandleSystemMessage function that is slightly different from the previous one and not able to find an example code or documentation explaining how to define it now.

I've understood should be something like that:

```
private async void HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
{
}
```

But what about code inside? How to manage things against the past?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Please see the below documentation for Updating your bot from V1 to V3
https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/support/upgrade-to-v3/#navtitle

Microsoft People’s provide a samples for developing own bots, see the below link contains some samples like Echo Bot, Sand Witch Bot and Pizza Bot etc..
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples

Similar to V1 bot, V3 bot having Activity types like below

[image]

If you want more information about Activity Types, see this below link

https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/activities.html

Example Code for HandleSystemMessage (Activity message) method.

```
  private async Task<Activity> HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
    {
        if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData)
        {
            // Implement user deletion here
            // If we handle user deletion, return a real message
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
        {
            // Handle conversation state changes, like members being added and removed
            // Use Activity.MembersAdded and Activity.MembersRemoved and Activity.Action for info
            // Not available in all channels
            IConversationUpdateActivity conversationupdate = message;
            using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, message))
            {
                var client = scope.Resolve<IConnectorClient>();
                if (conversationupdate.MembersAdded.Any())
                {
                    var reply = message.CreateReply();
                    foreach (var newMember in conversationupdate.MembersAdded)
                    {
                        if (newMember.Id != message.Recipient.Id)
                        {
                            reply.Text = $"Welcome {newMember.Name}! ";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            reply.Text = $"Welcome {message.From.Name}";
                        }
                        await client.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate)
        {
            // Handle add/remove from contact lists
            // Activity.From + Activity.Action represent what happened
            IContactRelationUpdateActivity update = message;
            using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, message))
            {
                var client = scope.Resolve<IConnectorClient>();
                if (update.Action.ToLower() == "add")
                {
                    var reply = message.CreateReply();
                    reply.Text = $"Welcome to the XXXX bot! To start an conversation with this bot send **XXXX** or **XXXX** command.\r \n if you need help, send the **Help** command.";
                    await client.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Typing)
        {
            // Handle knowing tha the user is typing
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Ping)
        {
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Hope it will be help to you

-Kishore

Comment: not sure why not this answer as accepted. just couple of thing you can add here regarding the namespace need to be add in default template when you paste this code . like using Autofac;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs; and using System.Linq. and thanks its works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the *Getting started* template which you can download [here](http://aka.ms/bf-bc-vstemplate). I copied it here for your convenience.

```
private Activity HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
{
    if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData)
    {
        // Implement user deletion here
        // If we handle user deletion, return a real message
    }
    else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
    {
        // Handle conversation state changes, like members being added and removed
        // Use Activity.MembersAdded and Activity.MembersRemoved and Activity.Action for info
        // Not available in all channels
    }
    else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate)
    {
        // Handle add/remove from contact lists
        // Activity.From + Activity.Action represent what happened
    }
    else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Typing)
    {
        // Handle knowing tha the user is typing
    }
    else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Ping)
    {
    }

    return null;
}
```